# Multithreaded client/server Chat room with GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, tcp, chatroom

I'm trying to make a multithreaded client/server chatroom with a gui using Java. At the moment I am able to create a functioning registration page and login page which use the map I have implemented using a hash map. When I log it does not launch the server or the client as I expect and I also get a message from the server that the connection fails however I am unable to identify why that is.

Client

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import static java.rmi.server.LogStream.log;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class chatClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

  
    Scanner scan ;
    Socket socket = null;
    DataInputStream input = null;
    DataOutputStream output = null;
    InetAddress ip;
    
    public chatClient() { //constructor
        try{                                             
            ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            socket = new Socket(ip, Constants.PORT);
            input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            
            scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            
        }catch(UnknownHostException ex){
            log("Client : " + ex.getMessage());
        }catch(IOException ex){
            log("Client : " + ex.getMessage());
           
        }
            
            
        }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        status = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        connectToServer = new javax.swing.JButton();
        privateConnection = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        messageArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        inputMessage = new java.awt.TextField();
        sendMessage = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        status.setText("Logged in as:");

        connectToServer.setText("Connect to server");
        connectToServer.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                connectToServerActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        privateConnection.setText("Private connection");

        messageArea.setColumns(20);
        messageArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(messageArea);

        inputMessage.setText("");

        sendMessage.setText("Send");
        sendMessage.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                sendMessageActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 382, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(inputMessage, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 246, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(sendMessage))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(status, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(connectToServer))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(privateConnection)))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(status)
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(connectToServer)
                    .addComponent(privateConnection))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 310, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(sendMessage, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(inputMessage, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(14, 14, 14))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void connectToServerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_connectToServerActionPerformed

    }//GEN-LAST:event_connectToServerActionPerformed

        private void sendMessage(){ 
        Thread sendMessage = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
               while(true){
                  String message = scan.nextLine();
                  
                  try{
                      output.writeUTF(message);
                  }catch(IOException ex){
                      log("writeMessageThread : " + ex.getMessage());
                  }
               }
            }
        });
        sendMessage.start();
    }
    
    private void sendMessageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_sendMessageActionPerformed
        sendMessage();
    }

        private void readMessage(){ //needs to implement the message area 
        Thread readMessage = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try{
                        String message = input.readUTF();
                        log(message);
                }catch(IOException ex){
                        log("readMessageThread : " + ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            }
        });
        readMessage.start();
    }
    
    
    
    
    private void log(String message){
        System.out.println(message);

    }//GEN-LAST:event_sendMessageActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        chatClient client = new chatClient();
        client.readMessage();
        client.sendMessage();

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new chatClient().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton connectToServer;
    private java.awt.TextField inputMessage;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea messageArea;
    private javax.swing.JButton privateConnection;
    private javax.swing.JButton sendMessage;
    private javax.swing.JLabel status;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Server

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import static java.rmi.server.LogStream.log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class chatServer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form chatServer
     */
    static List<ClientHandler> clients;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static int usersOnline = 0;
    Socket socket;
    
    public chatServer() {
    clients = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Constants.PORT);
        }catch(IOException ex) {
            log("Server : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }   
    
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        messageArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        inputMessage = new java.awt.TextField();
        sendMessage = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("IP address:");

        jButton1.setText("Start Server");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setText("Users logged in:");

        messageArea.setColumns(20);
        messageArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(messageArea);

        jLabel3.setText("Server side");

        inputMessage.setText("textField1");
        inputMessage.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                inputMessageActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        sendMessage.setText("Send");
        sendMessage.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                sendMessageActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(sendMessage)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1))))
                        .addGap(82, 82, 82))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(inputMessage, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 251, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(323, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 317, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(inputMessage, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(sendMessage))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    
    private void inputMessageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_inputMessageActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_inputMessageActionPerformed

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

    private void sendMessageActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_sendMessageActionPerformed

    }//GEN-LAST:event_sendMessageActionPerformed

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        chatServer server = new chatServer();
        server.waitingForConnection();
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {        
        public void run() {
        new chatServer().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
        /* Create and display the form */
    
    
     private void waitingForConnection(){
        log("Server running...");
        
        while(true) {
            try{
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            }catch(IOException ex) {
            log("Waiting for connection : " + ex.getMessage()); 
            }
            
            log("Client accepted the connection : " + socket.getInetAddress());
            usersOnline++;
            
            ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler(socket, "User" + usersOnline);
            
            Thread thread = new Thread(handler);
            addClient(handler);
            thread.start();
            
        }
    }
    
    


    public static List<ClientHandler> getClients(){
        return clients;
        
    }
    private void addClient(ClientHandler client){
        clients.add(client);
    }
    private void log(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
    }

       

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private java.awt.TextField inputMessage;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea messageArea;
    private javax.swing.JButton sendMessage;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Login

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package chatroomcwk;

import static com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.lib.ExsltDynamic.map;
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class login extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form login
     */
    public login() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        passwordText = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        userText = new java.awt.TextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        status = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Username:");

        jLabel2.setText("Password:");

        passwordText.setText("");
        passwordText.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                passwordTextActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        userText.setText("");
        userText.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                userTextActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("Login Page");

        jButton2.setText("Sign in");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        status.setText("Status");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addGap(91, 91, 91))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(userText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(passwordText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 176, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(status)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 130, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(userText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(passwordText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 166, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(21, 21, 21))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(status)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void passwordTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_passwordTextActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_passwordTextActionPerformed
    
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

        String username = userText.getText();
        String password = passwordText.getText();
        Component frame = null;

      //Create a map for users where put username as key and password as value
      Map<String, String> usersMap = new HashMap<>();
      usersMap.put("user1", "password1");
      usersMap.put("user2", "password2");

      //Create a map for the admin where put username as key and password as value
      Map<String, String> adminMap = new HashMap<>();
      adminMap.put("Admin", "password");

      // Implement your authentication
      if(usersMap.get(username) != null){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You are successfully logged in!");
           setVisible(false); //you can't see me!
           dispose(); //Destroy the JFrame object
           chatClient second = new chatClient();
           second.setVisible(true); //displays the client page

      } else if (adminMap.get(username) != null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You are successfully logged in!");
            setVisible(false); //you can't see me!
            dispose(); //Destroy the JFrame object
            chatServer third = new chatServer();
            third.setVisible(true); //displays the server page

      }else if (password.equals(map.usermap.get(username))){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You are successfully logged in!");
            setVisible(false); //you can't see me!
            dispose(); //Destroy the JFrame object
            chatServer third = new chatServer();
            third.setVisible(true); //displays the server page
      }    
      else {
            status.setText("Invalid username or password entered");
      }    
        
    
    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

    private void userTextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_userTextActionPerformed
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }//GEN-LAST:event_userTextActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        HashMap<String, String> users = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private static javax.swing.JPasswordField passwordText;
    private javax.swing.JLabel status;
    private static java.awt.TextField userText;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

Map

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;



public class map {
    
        public static HashMap<String, String> usermap = new HashMap<>();
        
        public HashMap<String, String> getUsers()
        {
            return usermap;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you with your ServerSocket: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/ServerSocketEx.java

Comment: You're creating too many objects: 2 chat servers and 2 chat clients. You should be creating one of each.

Comment: *When I log it does not launch the server* - the server should always be running. Then as a client you connect to the running server.

Comment: 1) Change every `catch` to add `ex.printStackTrace()`. ***Then..*** 2)  Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: If anything in my answer is confusing or unclear, please comment back to me.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comment, you're creating too many objects. For example, please look at the marked lines in the code below:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    chatServer server = new chatServer();  // (A)
    server.waitingForConnection();
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {        
        public void run() {
            new chatServer().setVisible(true); // (B)
        }
    });
}
```

On line (A) you create a new chatServer object (which should be re-named ChatServer by the way to comply with Java naming conventions), and then you have this object wait for connections off of the Swing event thread,... fine.

But then on line (B) you create a completely new chatServer object and display it as the chat server GUI. But this object is completely distinct from the object created on line (A), state changes that occur to the first object will not be reflected on the second object and visa versa, meaning that the GUI will be completely ignorant of any chat connections, not good.

Instead you should create one single chatServer object, have it wait for connections, and display it. Say by doing something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    final chatServer server = new chatServer();  // (A)   ** make it a final local variable **
    server.waitingForConnection();
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {        
        public void run() {
            // new chatServer().setVisible(true); // (B)  ** nope **
            server.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

---

Very same issue (and solution) for the chat client side of things.

---

Note that if this were my program, I'd rename the class to ChatServer, and I'd create a specific unambiguous thread for the connection waiting. Something like:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {        
        public void run() {
            final ChatServer server = new ChatServer(); // ** rename the class 
            new Thread(() -> server.waitingForConnection()).start();
            server.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```